# Incorrect value from event.value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, momentjs, angular-moment

I need to format date in angular material so i follow [this guide:](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yvejalpnggb?file=app%2Fdatepicker-moment-example.ts)

My code is in this `compoment.html:`

```
<mat-form-field>
            <input id="datanint" formControlName="dataBirth" (dateChange)="emitBirthDateChangeForValidation($event)" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>

        </mat-form-field>
```

my ts:

```
const FORMAT = {
    parse: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    }
  };


 providers:[
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: FORMAT }]
})


cosntructor(){
 this.dataBirth=new FormControl(moment());
}

     emitBirthDateChangeForValidation(event: any) {
            console.log(event);
            this.eventEmit.emit(event);
            }
        }
```

I copy this code also if the stackblitz project that I have just linked and when I print the event.value in the project linked I have  (when It's called data change):

```
value: 2020-10-01T22:00:00.000Z
```

In my own project when I print event.value I have (when It's called data change):

```
value: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: {…}, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
```

I don't have the moment object into event.value but I must have only date. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
import * as moment from 'moment';
//your function
emitBirthDateChangeForValidation(event: any) {
   console.log(moment(event.value._d).format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
}
```

Once you get the correct value, you can configure that array to retrieve relevant parts, just like I have extracted Date in MM/DD/YYYY format in the above code.

PS: I hope you have already done `npm install moment --save`

Comment: Yeah yours solution is good if you wanna take the value but I wanna understand why we are using both moment, the solution is the same but the result is different?

Comment: Its tough to say without seeing your actual code. Even the stackblitz link you shared is showing the default content without your edits and without any datechange. Both stackblitz edits and your actual code uploaded on stackblitz will be needed.  The concept is  MatMomentDateModule uses moment from moment.js, and similarily the values are extracted. By the way, I saw the issue in the code and rectified it as shown.